# Passing parameters from iframe to angular app component

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I need help concerning how can i pass params from an iframe from an external application to the angular app component.

my iframe looks like this:

```
 <iframe src="http://localhost:4200?idfiches=123456"></iframe>
```

the `http://localhost:4200` is the url for my angular application

In my app component i tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
parameterIdfiches: any;
  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
        this.parameterIdfiches = routeParams['idfiches'];
      });
  }
```

can someone please help me know what i missing here ?? thank you in advance guys ^^

Answer (score 0):

Angular documentation says you can find those query parameter in an observable called queryParamMap on the activeRoute

https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route

Does it help if you subscribe to that ?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activeRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParamMap => {
    this.parameterIdfiches = queryParamMap['idfiches'];
  });
}
```

By now params and queryParams are also available observables on the active route, but they will be deprecated in following angular versions. From the doc:

> Two older properties are still available. They are less capable than their replacements, discouraged, and may be deprecated in a future Angular version.
>
> params—An Observable that contains the required and optional parameters specific to the route. Use paramMap instead.
>
> queryParams—An Observable that contains the query parameters available to all routes. Use queryParamMap instead.

Comment: i only needed to do queryParams not Params. Thanks guys

Comment: Watch out: the documentation says it will be deprecated in following versiions. I would recommend using the paramsMap oder queryParamsMap.